# Can an application pretend to be a file or folder?

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net, file, filesystems

I've been looking into centralising my computer game saves to make it easier to backup and restore as well as putting them up on the cloud via dropbox but there in so may places that it makes it quite difficult. I noticed the Windows 7 and Vista now support Symbolic links so I've been playing around with that but I was wonder the follow:

Is it possible (code example or a point in the right direction) for an application (vb.net or C++) to spoof a file or folder?

E.g. Application A (a game like Diablo III or Civilization V) attempts to read or right from file A (the game save), application B (the save repository) detects this read/write request and pipes the request through itself preforming the request on file B (the actual game save in another location). Application A is in no way altered and treats the file normally.

Note: I realise there are many simple ways of preforming the same task in essence such as monitoring the use of Application A or periodically checking file A and copying it if it has been altered since the last check etc but all these methods have draw backs and less interested in making it work than if it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried this http://dropboxifier.codeplex.com/

Comment: @user629926: No I haven't, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is entirely possible to do this through a file system filter driver.  For information about these, take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968

Filter drivers can hook into CreateFile operations and redirect the create to a different place if you want, but they are much harder to write as compared to normal applications.  They run in kernel mode and must obey the limitations of drivers.

Comment: This sounds really interesting! Any ideas if there is something similar in Linux and mac?

Comment: @wkc; On linux, probably not very straight forward as windows from the enduser usability point of view. You may want to take a look at the [FUSE system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).

Answer (score 0):

You can "fake" special folders, like control panel does, but I don't think you can create anything accessible/writeable (in an easy way). I might be wrong though. I had the same idea once too (as a compatibility step for some company stuff), but couldn't find anything supporting an easy way to do it. It seems like it might be easier to be done on Unix systems (but that's obviously no option here). Also, I wouldn't expect any nice or easy solutions for .net.

Only approach I could think about right now, would be highjacking the according API calls (e.g. `FileOpen`) to reroute/manipipulate them (similar to what root kits do), but I wouldn't say that's a good idea, considering it might be detected as possible malware or cheats by things like punkbuster or antivirus solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes or no depending on (using your terms) the level of abstraction that Application A is using.

If Application A is performing a `CreateFile` wto start access and passing a fixed filesystem path then Application B would need to emulate a file system and do so in the kernel.

On the other hand if Application A were to user HTTP with RESTful URLs then the HTTP server could answer all requests from files or by dynamically creating the content.

So the question can only be answered in specific by knowing the details of Application A.

Comment: Not necessarily "in kernel". E.g. http://dokan-dev.net/en/about/ is a sort of FUSE for Windows.

Comment: @Richard: I meant a full windows/linux/mac application writing or reading to the file-system. I've got a web background so I'm already aware of web services.

Comment: @Mat looks to be like Dokan provides a device driver so you don't need to write it yourself. But it is still based on a device driver.